# AJAX file upload with XMLHttpRequest() and codeigniter gives error - "You did not select a file to upload."

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

The JS file -

```
var doUpload =  function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.stopPropagation();        
        // get the file-input id
        var fileId = document.getElementById('logo_upload');    

        // this variable makes an object which accept key/value pairs which could be sent via ajax.send
        var formObj = new FormData();

        // append currently selected file to the dataObject            
        formObj.append('file', fileId.files[0]);        


        // this is a variable to check in the php script (controller if the codeIgniter is used)
        formObj.append('error-check', true);
        formObj.append('finish-check', true);

        // let's make the ajax request object
        var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajaxReq.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (ajaxReq.readyState==4 && ajaxReq.status==200)
            {
                console.log('this is the response area');
                console.log(ajaxReq.responseText);
            }
        }

        ajaxReq.open('POST', serverUrl+"schoolController/logoImageuploadAction");
        ajaxReq.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');ajaxRequest.send();
        ajaxReq.send(formObj);

}


$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#school_logo_upload").on('change',  function(event){           
        $("#logo_image_form").submit();      
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#school_logo_image_form").on('submit', function(event){      
        doUpload(event);
        console.log('after upload form');
    });

});
```

html form -

```
<form name="logo_photo" id="school_logo_image_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                <input type="file" id="school_logo_upload" name="file"/>

<!--                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" /> -->
            </form>
```

codeigniter controller function -

```
 function logoImageuploadAction() {
        //testing controller
        $this->load->model('imageUploadManager');
        $result = $this->imageUploadManager->schoolLogoUpload();

        echo $result;
    }
```

the codeigniter model function -

```
function schoolLogoUpload() {

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $testArray = array('errror' => $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $testArray = array('successss' => $data);
        }

       return json_encode($testArray);
    }
```

the return is always - `"{"errror":{"error":"<p>You did not select a file to upload.<\/p>"}}"`

although when i print the $_FILES array with json encode in the model i get -

```
{"file":{"name":"filename.gif","type":"image\/gif","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php7771.tmp","error":0,"size":12558}}
```

can some one please point to what am i missing here, any help will be appriciated, Thanks!!!

Comment: Also the temp file (`like "php7771.tmp" in this case`) is not available in the wamp/tmp folder

Answer (score 0):

pass the file name in `$this->upload->do_upload()` function. by default CI suppose that the file parameter is `userfile`. so you need to do something like `$this->upload->do_upload($_FILE['file']['name'])`

Comment: i have changed the line to `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['file']['name']))` still getting the error as "You did not select a file to upload."

Comment: Also the temp file (like "php7771.tmp" in this case) is not available in the wamp/tmp folder

Comment: Add this line. define( 'IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
in our config/constants.php

Answer (score 0):

> <input type="file" id="school_logo_upload" name="**file**"/>

You should tell CI your input file name by passing it to do_upload() function as a parameter. like so:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $testArray = array('errror' => $error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ajaxReq.open('POST', serverUrl+"schoolController/logoImageuploadAction");
>           ajaxReq.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');ajaxRequest.send();
>           ajaxReq.send(formObj);

You are sending to soon with your first "ajaxRequest.send();" please remove and try again